# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Mastransit.RavbbitMqTransport.IRabbitMqHost'

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

Trying to implement RabbitMQ With ASP.NET Core - Microservice Communication With MassTransit.In the configuraton file showing the error
'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Mastransit.RabbitMqTransport.IRabbitMqHost'

```cs
public static class BusConfigurator
{
    public static IBusControl ConfigureBus(Action<IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator, IRabbitMqHost> registrationAction = null)
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 1;
            cfg.PurgeOnStartup = true;
            IRabbitMqHost  hst = cfg.Host(new Uri(Busconstants.RabbitMqUri), hst =>
            {
                hst.Username(Busconstants.username);
                hst.Password(Busconstants.password);                 
            });
            registrationAction?.Invoke(cfg, hst);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your using an ancient version of the API as a reference, I'd suggest following the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/).

Comment: Yes That's it! Thank you Chris Patterson